# Reduction first dimension of ndarray - keep first and last elements

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a 3D matrix I want to reduce. I would like to reduce the first dimension only to around 10 elements (it is best if it is 10 but not necessary). I used this code for that:

```
import numpy
m = numpy.random.rand(37,2,100)
new_m = m[0:-1:int(m.shape[0]/10)]
# new_m.shape = (12, 2, 100)
```

My **problem** is the following: I want the first and last elements of this first dimension to be the same than my original matrix.
But with my current code, this condition does not hold for the last element:

```
new_m[0,:,:2], new_m[-1,:,:2]
#[[ 0.06081972  0.91343839] [ 0.89614534  0.33846807]]
#[[ 0.37289341  0.62491196] [ 0.30603305  0.1442681 ]]
m[0,:,:2], m[-1,:,:2]
#[[ 0.06081972  0.91343839] [ 0.89614534  0.33846807]]
#[[ 0.28143018  0.10626664] [ 0.30334235  0.29616713]]
```

As you can see `new_m[-1]` is not equal to `m[-1]`, and I would like them to be.

My **tries/ideas**:

- I tried to append `m[-1]` to `new_m` however I got this error:

  > AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
- I also thought about doing `new_m[-1] = m[-1]`, but I would like the space between the steps to be proportional (i.e. steps well separated).

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using numpy, you can exploit fancy indexing. We'll also use `linespace`, which generates evenly spaced points in a range, including endpoints. The arguments are similar to what you'd pass to `range` or your indexing method.

```
indexes = np.linspace(0, len(m) - 1, 10, dtype=int)
new_m = m[indexes]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that `linspace` could take `dtype` as argument. I'll just have to update my old numpy version (v1.8.2) since it appears in v1.9.